# mongod service not started but mongod --config /etc/mongod.conf works

Tags: mongodb

I am unable to start the mongod service using command service mongod start. But I run then command mongod --config /etc/mongod.conf , the service is started. I am ubanble to figure out the problem. Please help me.

Comment: OS Version? MongoDB version?

Comment: Please include the OS with version, MongoDB version, your config file / command line options, relevant excerpts from the log file, and any error messages that you got along with what commands or steps you did to get the errors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When installing MongoDB via a package, the **mongod** service is automatically configured to run with **/etc/mongod.conf** as config file in **/etc/init.d/mongod** init script.

That means that you can start the **mongod** service without the **--config** option.

http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-ubuntu/

Hope that helps.